# Trace32 is there way to know if PRACTICE cmm finished?

Tags: trace32, lauterbach

I am using RCL for controlling Trace32 remotely.
It is well-known that when running any PRACTICE command interactively (e.g. `cd.do my_script.cmm`) the command itself completes immediately, while the CMM script continues to run.

Same applies when executing command remotely.

My question: if there any function in Trace32 that I could call and determine if any CMM is currently running? Not code (that one is `STATE.RUN()`), but PRACTICE script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answer provided by @dev15:

> There is hidden API `dbg.library.t32_getpracticestate()` which is similar to `T32_GetPracticeState`.

Couldn't accept previous as answer because my question was specifically for RCL, not ctype DLL.

Also can be used addition check of stack depth `dbg.fnc.practice_stackdepth()`  to determine if Trace32 is in middle of CMM script or not.

Answer (score 4):

Use the function

`int T32_GetPracticeState ( int *pstate );`

to find out if a PRACTICE script is currently running. See api_remote_c.pdf for details and possible values of `pstate`.

Comment: Unfortunately is not supported by RCL... thanks anyway

Comment: It is a little bit hidden, because normally you shouldn't need it. You can access it by using `dbg.library.t32_getpracticestate()`.

Comment: Maybe you are using InterCom instead of RCL? Sending commands from one PowerView instance to another one? Like `InterCom.execute <instance_name> CD.DO my_script.cmm`?

Comment: @dev15 man you are my savior!!! Put your comment as answer, i'll reward you points. I even contacted Lauterbach support about it and they were helpless.